# How to record audio along with video in deepin screen recorder?

Tags: sound

I am unable to record audio along with video in **Deepin screen recorder**.

I can't find settings too. When i click the icon, it directly asks me to select the recording screen area, and starts recording.

Is there any way or should i switch to another application ?

I am using ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Deepin Screen Recorder is a simple tool designed to record the screen. It does not support recording audio.

- *Is there any way?* You can record sound using another application such as Audacity, and afterwards combine sound and video using a video editor.
- *Should I switch to another application?* That is your preference. There are screencasting applications that support the recording of both screen and audio, some more simple (Simple Screen Recorder) and others very powerfull (OBS Studio).